# How to debug expected DOM behaviour in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
$('.user_info').click(function(){
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    rel_value = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('#' + rel_value).css({top: pos.top + 'px', left: pos.left + 'px'});
    $('#' + rel_value).show('slow');

    $('#' + rel_value).hover(function(){}, function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });

    return false;
});
```

When I click on link with class `user_info`, it shows div identified by `'#' + rel_value`. The problem is that div shows but at the same times fades out (`$(this).fadeOut('slow');`) even though I have specified this in mouseout parameter.

What I want is that div should only go away when mouse leaves its area. How to do this?

### Edit

Strange, the same code works on jsbin but not on my page: jQuery version is also same.

http://jsbin.com/epifu3

Comment: Strange, the same code works on jsbin but not on my page: jquery version is also same.

http://jsbin.com/epifu3

Comment: The code you have above works fine for me in Firefox, IE and Chrome. The jsbin version works as well both online and when I pulled the code out and ran it on my desktop. Maybe you have something else interfering? Do you have code elsewhere on the page that is also using the same elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is normal that it disappears, because, when you click on element1, your mouse is on element1, therefore, not on element2( '#' + rel_value).

Try this instead: add a class (example:"tobeShown") to all the elements that have the id you set normally via your `'#' + rel_value`, and attach the hover() behaviours to them separately from your click function.

```
$('.tobeShown').hover(function(){}, function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });

$('.user_info').click(function(){
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    rel_value = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('#' + rel_value).css({top: pos.top + 'px', left: pos.left + 'px'});
    $('#' + rel_value).show('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: that did not work either. Strange, the same code works on jsbin but not on my page: jquery version is also same.

http://jsbin.com/epifu3

Comment: look: setting the mouseout event inside the click event is plain wrong: think about it. Everytime the user clicks on your element, it will recreate the function, and the binding. Not very efficient.

I tried my code and it works on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/epifu3/2/  as for your page, you should put it online. There is nothing magick: an error must be inside of it, since you say it works on jsbin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `hover` with `mouseleave`?

Comment: Have you got a link to live page demonstrating the problem? I would like to debug it with firebug

Comment: Strange, the same code works on jsbin but not on my page: jquery version is also same.

http://jsbin.com/epifu3

Answer (score 0):

`.hover()` fires for any container leave action as well, it's equivalent to `mouseleave` in your case.  Have you tried the vanilla `.mouseout()` event instead?

```
$('#' + rel_value).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

It's hard to say exactly without seeing the markup, but not using jQuery's custom event for this seems more of what you're after.

Comment: Tried that too. Strange, the same code works on jsbin but not on my page: jquery version is also same.

http://jsbin.com/epifu3